# Angular 2 - Highcharts lib

Tags: angular, highcharts, import

People,
I'm using highcharts lib, from: angular2-highcharts.

At the begining,I had the famous issue: require() not found, when you use: 
    ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')) on @NgModules/imports[].

But that one is tottaly ok.

The question is, when I use **ng serve** to serve my app, sometimes it works and show me the beauty chart, but in the most part of time, it shows me: **Calling function 'ChartModule', function calls are not supported.**

And that makes me think, so I tried to comment the line that shows me the component, during serving, save and after that uncomment and it works sooooo much. But it's not too good.

I had the conclusion my app is trying to import highcharts (by the line: **import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';**) before some other import...

I've been think in force the import to be did after everything, how can I do it?

If somebody have another suggestion, pleeaasee, talk to me.

Tks Guys.

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: Actually I found other highcharts' lib, and I'm using it, It's ng2-highcharts, I think it's working. But Thanks for asking!